# Why doesn't bind notice updates to a variable?

Tags: javascript, bind

Why doesn't bind notice changes to a variables value?  Also, why doesn't bind accept an uncleared variable like `warrior.bind({'name': 'Rob3'}, 'ninja')`

```
function warrior(kind){
  console.log(this.name);
}

var me = {'name': 'Rob'}    
var ninja = warrior.bind(me, "ninja");
ninja();
me = {'name': 'Rob2'};
ninja();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `me = {'name': 'Rob2'};` this creates an entirely new object and assigns it into the `me` variable. The `ninja` function is still bound to the old `me`. Instead, you need to keep the same object, but only modify its properties, like this:

```
me.name = 'Rob2';
```

Not sure what the problem is with using an object literal in the `warrior.bind` function, this works for me, but you want be able to change the object later.

Comment: ya my mistake on the second part, it works now.  I must have just been typing it in wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are creating new object and assigning reference of this newly created object to `me` variable. You should update properties if you want to continue to use binding instead of creating new object.

```
function warrior(kind){
  console.log(this.name);
}

var me = {'name': 'Rob'}    
var ninja = warrior.bind(me, "ninja");
ninja();
me.name = 'Rob2'; // Do not create new object. Update already existing one.
ninja();
```